Is there a solid and maintained GraphQL query builder for TypeScript?
I'm looking for a GraphQL query builder library that is well maintained, with a nice DX and an active community around it (or backed by an active company).
I need to generate queries dynamically based on a queryTree constructed by user's input.
For example: I want to convert the follow operations
[
  { operation: 'container', args: {} },
  { operation: 'from', args: { address: 'alpine:3.16.2' } }
]

Into an actual GraphQL query like this:
{ 
  container($address: String) { 
    from (address: $address) 
  } 
}

Right now, I have a custom homemade solution but I'm looking for a better solution that is well maintained and bullet proof.
I've looking through multiples libraries but they are either outdated or not provide what I'm looking for.
The only libraries I found that matches my needs are:

gql-query-builder but it's not maintened anymore.
typed-graphql-builder but the project look pretty young. I'm not sure it's bullet proof.

I've also check on Apollo client but I couldn't find a query builder in the source code.
Do anyone knows a nice and maintened implementation of such a query builder?
